# How to force even number of pages in output document?

Tags: output, clearpage

Similar things have been asked, but I would like to know how to do in order to have my output PDF be an even-number-of-pages document. This code

```
\AtEndDocument{\cleardoublepage}
```

only makes the "even-LaTeX-page" to be the last, but in my document the last LaTeX-page (122) is 127th of the entire document. I want the "output PDF" to be even for printing reasons. Thanks

Comment: You have some answers below, but I wonder about the wisdom of this. Presumably your document will be printed double sided (since `\cleardoublepage` does nothing when not using `twoside`). Normally books always place the odd pages on the right hand side, but your page 1 must be on the left hand side, which is unusual. I'd put the `\cleardoublepage` before page 1, so you get an extra blank page there and page 1 will then start on an odd page of the entire document. Perhaps `\frontmatter` at the start of your document and `\mainmatter` just before your page one would suit you better.

Answer (score 2):

Here I define the extra page if needed to be totally blank.  I provide a commented `\renewcommand` that instead prints "Intentionally left blank" on the extra page.

Whether or not you uncomment the `%\clearpage Page 2 content` line, the document will contain 2 pdf pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcommand\finishonevenpage{%
  \clearpage\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\blankpage\fi}
\newcommand\blankpage{\clearpage\mbox{}}% EMPTY EXTRA PAGE IF NEEDED
%\renewcommand{\blankpage}{
%  \clearpage
%  \begin{center}
%    {\textsc{\rule{0em}{4.5in}Intentionally left blank.}}
%  \end{center}
%}
\begin{document}
Page 1 content
%\clearpage Page 2 content
\finishonevenpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what class you are using but the `memoir` class (encompasses the `book`, `report` and `article` classes) has a `\leavespergathering{<num>}` macro.

In your case:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\leavespergathering{4}
...
```

will work to give you 128 pages, the last being blank.

A *gathering* --- a publishers term --- consists of a number of leaves (so twice that of pages) and publishers like a document to have an integral number of gatherings for printing. The `leavespergathering{<num>}` results in a document with a multiple of `2<num>` pages; if there are less than `2<num>` typeset pages the extras are blank.